# Hidden localization of symbols via Module and Interpretation

Tags: scoping

I want to hide `Module`'s symbol names (such as `x$23118`) from the end user of a package I am developing. To give some context: The user inputs a equation into a function that holds its arguments and replaces all occouring symbols via `Module` to protect the user from stray definitions. The output of the function, however, should still display the original symbol names to not confuse the user and to improve readability (`x` is a lot nicer than `x$23118`, especially if the equation has more than one independent variable).

The function I wrote for localizing the symbols and keeping their initial names is

```
SetAttributes[localize, HoldAll];    
localize[x_] := Interpretation[SymbolName@Unevaluated@x, Module[{x}, x]]
```

which seems to work for protecting from stray definitions

```
x = 1;
localize@x (*outputs x, and upon evaluating the output cell again yields x$23553 *)
```

What makes me question this approach is the following, try:

```
{localize@x, localize@x} // Union (* outputs {x} 
and upon evaluating the output cell again yields {x$23554}  *)
```

and compare with

```
{Module[{x}, x], Module[{x}, x]} // Union (* yields {x$23118, x$23119}*)
```

From `{localize@x, localize@x} // Union` I expected an output cell containing `{x,x}` that upon repeated evaluation would evaluate to what `{Module[{x}, x], Module[{x}, x]} // Union` directly gave.

In my use case the behavior shown is actually beneficial but I would like to:

1. Understand why the behavior is the way it is
2. Know if this method is safe to use for localizing symbols

Comment: The same questions of course apply for something like `localize[x : {__}] := 
 Interpretation[SymbolName /@ Unevaluated /@ Unevaluated@x, 
  Module[x, x]]` for localizing multiple symbols at once

Comment: Can you explain why you want this?  It seems like a really really awful idea to me.  But I don't know what you want to use it for so maybe it is reasonable ... I just can't imagine how though. Why awful?  It makes one thing look like another, there *will* be confusion.  `Interpretation` only works in notebooks, and only interacts with notebooks.  The output still has head `Interpretation` and can't be computed with.  Interesting things only happen when you copy and paste the output or re-evaluate the output cell, as it's all about interpretation of box forms.

Comment: To understand the behaviour, try `res = {localize[x], localize[x]}; InputForm[res]`.  For as long as we don't interact with the front end and notebooks, `Interpretation` behaves as if it were `sym` with `SetAttributes[sym, HoldRest]`.

Comment: @Szabolcs I know what you mean when you say that hiding something like this from the user is a bad idea (and I definitely agree) but from experience I know that people not too familiar with Mathematica (i.e. Matlab users) tend to both be very casual with short symbol names (e.g. `x`) and global symbols at the same time which leads to disbelieve when stuff inevitable goes awry. A small part of what I am developing is a function that turns an impedance network description like  `z1 + z2 || z3 ` into the network's transfer function. (+ corresponds to series; || to parallel connection)

Comment: Can you explain better how these "localized" symbols will be used?  It is only for displaying output?  Do users interact with them?  If yes, how?  Can you give a short and trivial example of how a user might interact with these?  Can you explain "localization" better?  Localized to what scope?  Maybe in chat?